# wp_dropdown_pages : choose post status to list in dropdown

Tags: dropdown, post-status

I would like to create a dropdown of all *schedule* and *publish* CPT posts.

I seems function [wp_dropdown_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_pages/) only displays list of *publish* posts, is it possible to choose which post states to display ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_pages/) for the function, you can see that the arguments to the function are passed directly through to [`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/). That function supports a `post_status` argument that can be an array of statuses. So to do what you want all you need to do is pass the post statuses you want into a `post_status` argument of `wp_dropdown_pages()`:

```
wp_dropdown_pages( arrray(
    'post_status' => array( 'future', 'publish' ),
) );
```

Comment: ps: I added a ticket [#43355](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43355) to improve the inline documentation for `wp_dropdown_pages()`.